# GNOME3 - Mixed old and new look

Tags: gnome

Why do various application bars like the menu bar look obsolote in Natty+GNOME 3 compared with Fedora ? See the difference between window panels in F15 Gnome [here](http://www.yorkim.be/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/fedora-15-gnome3.png) and a screenshot from my desktop:
[image: Screenshot of desktop - notice the menus of Firefox they look from almost Win95 era!]

While the main interface is quite similar in both the OS.

Comment: I am not sure what I am looking for?  Are you suggesting that the same theme is used in both cases, but look different from one another?

Comment: Look at the title bar, for example, in F15 picture (given as link) it looks crystalline with better finished looks. While the title bar and the menu bar of FF in the above picture look like WIN95 based.

Comment: Yes, in both cases it is the default theme.

Comment: You say it is the default theme...I have to ask, because I do not know...does F15 use a different default theme relative to what Gnome 3 uses.  Fedora is known, like Ubuntu, for putting their special little twists into the GUI.  It looks like two different themes to me.

Comment: your'e theme is broken, the GTK theme you're using is called Raleigh and it was a bug in gnome 2.32 affecting gnome-settings-daemon, yet you still have it.

Comment: I have changed now, but still cannot find Adwaita.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ubuntu theme was not ported to GTK+ 3 yet and therefore only a fallback is available. This also affects the current 11.10 Alpha 1 and will most certainely change in the future prior to the Oneiric Release and might be ported back to Natty (I am referring to [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/06/ubuntu-11-10-alpha-1-released/#comment-216836824)).

You can also try to manually set the theme to "Adwaita" in your appearance preferences rather then waiting for the Ubuntu themes beeing ported which should have been installed with Gnome 3 if you want the standard look (e.g. like in Fedora).

Comment: Hi, but it seems Adwaita is not installed with the GNOME3. It is not listed in the tweak tool.

Comment: Okay, then you could try and install gnome-themes-standard, as suggested in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46960/gnome3-mixed-old-and-new-look/46982#46982). That should work.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a common issue with the installed theme. This can be fixed by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-accessibility-themes
sudo apt-get install gnome-themes-standard
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the Adwaita theme installed?  I had this problem when I added the Gnome3 repos and I had to manually add Adwaita.